# Clarification about sieve rules needed ... :contains with or without anyof/allof?

Tags: imap, dovecot, sieve-rules

I started refining my sieve rules recently and became a bit unsure about how `:contains` actually works. I checked out http://sieve.mozdev.org/reference.html but it still didn't clear up the question I had.

Say I have the following rule:

```
if
    header :contains ["List-Id", "X-Mailinglist", "X-Mailing-List"] [
        "ros-dev.reactos.org",
        "ros-general.reactos.org"
    ]
{
    fileinto "Lists/ReactOS";
    stop;
}
```

does this mean (and that **would be** my idea of how I want it to work) automatically that *any of* the listed header fields `["List-Id", "X-Mailinglist", "X-Mailing-List"]` should contain *any of* the given values `["ros-dev.reactos.org", "ros-general.reactos.org"]` or need I say explicitly `if anyof (...)` like this?:

```
if anyof (
    header :contains ["List-Id", "X-Mailinglist", "X-Mailing-List"] [
        "ros-dev.reactos.org",
        "ros-general.reactos.org"
    ]
)
{
    fileinto "Lists/ReactOS";
    stop;
}
```

... for this desired outcome? Or do the two lists not match **each element of the first against each element of the second list** *anyway*?

**NB:** I know that the comma-separated conditions are affected by `anyof` and `allof` respectively. So `if anyof (condition1, condition2)` means (pseudo-code) `if (condition1 or condition2)` and `if allof (condition1, condition2)` means `if (condition1 and condition2)`. Understanding this aspect is *not* my problem.

What I fail to understand, though, is whether `anyof` and `allof` respectively influence either or both **of the lists in a `:contains` clause**. In the above example there is a list for the header fields and a list of values to match against.

---

Essentially the question boils down to whether or not there is a semantic difference between the two above snippets. And if not, then whether the first one *means* this:

```
if anyof (
    header :contains ["List-Id", "X-Mailinglist", "X-Mailing-List"] "ros-dev.reactos.org",
    header :contains ["List-Id", "X-Mailinglist", "X-Mailing-List"] "ros-general.reactos.org"
)
{
    fileinto "Lists/ReactOS";
    stop;
}
```

... or this:

```
if allof (
    header :contains ["List-Id", "X-Mailinglist", "X-Mailing-List"] "ros-dev.reactos.org",
    header :contains ["List-Id", "X-Mailinglist", "X-Mailing-List"] "ros-general.reactos.org"
)
{
    fileinto "Lists/ReactOS";
    stop;
}
```

... or something else altogether.

Answer (score 1):

`anyof` means that if any single header contains one of the alternative values, then the whole condition become `true`, nevertheless the rest headers contains something else.

`anyof` ALSO becomes `true` when all the headers contains the predefined values. This is the relaxed condition.

`allof` ONLY becomes `true` when all the headers contains the predefined values. This is the strict condition.

Comment: thanks for your time, but this is exactly the part that I understood already. I needed no clarification for that part. However, I added some more sentences in the hope that I can explain what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

As the [reference you indicated](https://thsmi.github.io/sieve-reference/en/test/core/header.html) as well as the [RFC 3028 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3028#section-5.7) says for the `header` test,

> The "header" test evaluates to true if any header name matches any key.

That is, each header name is compared to each value, and if any of the cross-product is a match, then the test passes. The comparator specified (`:contains` in your case) is used for each individual comparison. Basically, your first re-write into `anyof` is correct.

The use of `anyof` and `allof` is when there are multiple tests that you want to use, but sometimes you can pack a lot of logic into one "test", as you have here.